# JMeter - response time calculation

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

Can someone explain me please how JMeter calculate response time?

I need to understand this graph: [Response Times Over Time](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Response time is also known as `time to last byte` while Latency is `time to first byte`:

- **Time to last byte** - time from the moment the request was sent till the last resource is finished downloading.
- **Time to first byte** - time from the moment the request was sent till the first byte of the first resource is received back.

Is that what you wanted to know or have I misunderstood your question?

**EDIT:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303535/meaning-and-calculation-formulas-for-processing-time-latency-and-response-time) is a more detailed explanation off all possible performance measurements.