# How can we measure the Server Processing Time,Page Loading Time,Page Rendering Time and Page Size from Apache Jmeter

Tags: performance, apache, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I measure the following points

- Server Processing Time
- Page Loading Time
- Page Rendering Time
- Page Size

from Apache Jmeter?

Is there any suitable listener to measure all these points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With aggregate report Or csv / xml results you get nearly all the infos you can regarding response times BUT:

- Server Processing Time: you cannot get this one as jmeter act on client side it includes network time, so you need to add some profiling data or look at access logs
- Page Loading Time : if it's page response time yes
- Page Rendering Time : no as jmeter is not a browser, furthermore rendering occurs on client side so what interests you in load testing is time to get response.
- Page Size: yes

I suggest you read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/-Solutions-

Answer (score 2):

```
Server processing time = time to first byte - request sent
Page loading time = time to last byte - time to first byte
Page size = Response size

Page rendering time - you'll have to use GUI testing tools for this one.
E.g. 
  Chrome has Ctrl+Shift+i > Timeline tab
  Firefox has Firebug > Net tab.
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397700/jmeter-response-time-calculation) for more info on these phrases mentioned above.