# Is there any way to measure Server Processing Time using JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Is there any way to measure Server processing Time in JMeter whether it's require manual calculation.I am able to measure (Response Time/ Latency) and (Elapsed Time) of request but unable to get processing Time.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986721/how-can-we-measure-the-server-processing-time-page-loading-time-page-rendering-t/11987420#11987420 . If it's a duplicate I suggest you delete your question

Comment: Yes but There answer for processing Time is wrong.

Comment: I don't think so. Do you have a reference that says it is ?

Comment: No but I think it can measure from client side by subtracting some values from response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get this using JMeter.

Because to do it you would need the time taken between the server sending the first byte and the client receiving it (network time), as you don't have it ....

Even with this, I am not sure it would be accurate, as server can continue processing while starting to write bytes in the buffer of the response.

So my answer is that it's not possible with JMeter alone.

Comment: So Is it ok to say latency = Server Processing Time because this is the time just before sending the request and fetching the first response PLUS the time for connection.
So Server Processing Time = Latency - Connect time.