# How to calculate the response time in Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have used jmeter 2.8.
I have tested Http request using web service calls. I need to calculate response time. I do not know how to calculate it.
I have refere this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397700/jmeter-response-time-calculation). I think they have used some plugin in Jmeter. Is there need to use plugin for calculating response time?

Also in that question **time to last byte** and **time to first byte** are mentioned.
Where can these two variables found n Jmeter?
There are a lot of listeners in jmeter. If i need to know the response time mean which listener use?

Comment: May i know why i'm getting downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add any listener:

- run your test in non-gui mode
- generate a Csv file
- then once test has ended , load csv using Response time graph listener

See this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: thank you.I have created csv file.In that file have <httpSample t="57507" lt="57507" ts="1357191349494" s="true" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="434"/>.I think t is response time/sec.this is ok for 1 request.How can i see this csv file for total time taken if i send 100request?.It ll display only every request only.

Comment: What you are showing is not a csv output. It's xml. Read the article it gives the exact configuration to output csv, then you add a resp time graph listener after the run and reread the generated file, you will get the graphs