# what is the sample time represent to this graph in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

[image]

I need to understand this graph.what is **sample time(ms)** in this graph? which is refer to response time? can you someone tell me.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397700/jmeter-response-time-calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample time is the total amount of time in milliseconds, required to load a page completely(response to a query).

Comment: This is not the case in jmeter, if by load you mean render, see so link in comment for the answer