# Average time displayed by JMeter doesn't matches the Elapsed time in Fiddler for a HTTP request

Tags: jmeter, fiddler, response-time

Scenario:

A JMeter script for a single user with a single HTTP request is configured to run via localhost port 8888 (port sniffed by Fiddler).
The request travels properly to the server and a successful response is received.
The issue is, the Average time displayed in the Listener for the HTTP response in not matching with the overal elapsed time of Fiddler for that request.
e.g. If the Average time displayed is of 24 millisecond, Fiddler reports 15 millisecond (Note: high-resolution timers enabled in Fiddler)

I am trying to figure out why is JMeter consuming a small bit of extra time for each request, what network or system processing element its considering additional to those of Fiddler.

Comment: Further context on this question can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/pMnxwV7LDsQ

Answer (score 0):

JMeter consumes a bit of extra time when you run in GUI mode. In Non- GUI the response is better. The details on response time can be read here [JMeter - response time calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397700/jmeter-response-time-calculation)